# What is the difference between どのぐらい and どれぐらい?

Tags: usage, particle-くらい

I just heard a sentence this morning - "how much money do you have?"

> お金、どれぐらい　ある？

I have always been taught "how much" is どのぐらい so hearing どれぐらい has caught me off-guard.

As I recall we use この with an object, and これ when there is not one.
So...

> お金、どれぐらい　ある？
>
> どのぐらい　お金が　ある？

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

どれくらい, どれぐらい, どのくらい, and どのぐらい are used interchangeably.

> お金、どれくらいある？/お金はどれくらいありますか。
> お金、どれぐらいある？/お金はどれぐらいありますか。
> お金、どのくらいある？/お金はどのくらいありますか。
> お金、どのぐらいある？/お金はどのぐらいありますか。
>
> どれくらいお金ある？/どれくらい(の)お金がありますか。
> どれぐらいお金ある？/どれぐらい(の)お金がありますか。
> どのくらいお金ある？/どのくらい(の)お金がありますか。
> どのぐらいお金ある？/どのぐらい(の)お金がありますか。

All sound fine to me. どれくらい, どのくらい etc. modify a 用言 (=ある/あります) and どのくらい**の**, どれくらい**の** etc. modifiy a 名詞 (=お金).

Comment: Do you know why is く sometimes voiced to ぐ (くらい-> ぐらい)?

Comment: @Szymon I don't know the reason. It seems like in Edo period there were distinctions such as (1)体言には「ぐらい」が付く。
(2)「この・その・あの・どの」には「くらい」が付く。
(3)用言や助動詞には、普通は「ぐらい」が付くが，「くらい」が付くこともある。 but in modern Japanese we don't have such restrictions anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**どれぐらい と どのぐらい**

サイズや量や数に対しては "どれぐらい" を使っていることが多くて、
期間の場合は "どのぐらい" が使われていることが多いかなと思います。

例：
 1. どれぐらいの大きさであれば宜しいでしょうか。 
 2. その車を買うのにどれぐらいのお金が要るだろう。
 3. あと、どれぐらいのりんごがこの箱に入れるかな。
 4. 区役所までバスでどのぐらいかかりますか。